# Time conversion to ISO string is not correct with text field displayed

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I have a text field in an MVC application that displays the date and time.  The date is created using a datepicker and the time I add to the text field.
An example of the text is as follows:

```
10/23/2015 12:00 AM
```

I want to create a Date object with this time in ISO 8601 format.  The date will be used to create an event in a fullcalendar jquery plugin.
When I try to create the Date object, the ISO string is:

```
2015-10-23T04:00:00.000Z
```

It should be `2015-10-23T00:00:00.000Z` to represent midnight on that day.
This is my code:

```
<label id="schedule_start_date_lbl">Start Date: </label>
<input id="schedule_start_date" type="text" />

var startDayIndex = getDayIndex($('#rotation_start_time_txt').val());
$("#schedule_start_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) { return [date.getDay() == startDayIndex, ""] },
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $('#schedule_end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
    },
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {           
        var rotation_txt = $('#rotation_start_time_txt').val();
        var time = rotation_txt.substr(rotation_txt.indexOf(',') + 1);
        $(this).val(selectedDate + time.toString(' HH:mm tt').toString());
    }
});

    $("#rotation_schedule_btn").click(function () {
//text value in schedule_start_date is: 10/23/2015 12:00 AM
 var startDate = new Date($('#schedule_start_date').val()).toISOString();
 //Value displayed is 2015-10-23T04:00:00.000Z
 alert('startDate: ' + startDate);
});
```

Why is the time value off by 4 hours?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
I need to add to the Date objects after they are created.  Creating the Date object using the function in the answer below is not creating it in UTC format.  It can be **displayed** in that format but when I am creating events in the fullcalendar control, the date *must* be in UTC format and they are not.
This is my function to create a schedule:

```
 $("#rotation_schedule_btn").click(function () {
    //create member list order    
    var memberList = [];         
    $("#rotationList li").each(function () {
        memberList.push({
            id: $(this).attr('id'),
            name: $(this).text(),
            color: $(this).css('background-color')
        })
    });

    //start and end date and time for new schedule
    var startDate = convertTextToDate($('#schedule_start_date').val())
    var endDate = convertTextToDate($('#schedule_end_date').val());

    //remove events between startDate & endDate
    $('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (event) {
        if (event.start.toDate() >= startDate && event.start.toDate() <= endDate
               || event.end.toDate() >= startDate && event.end.toDate() <= endDate) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    //Create events from rotation schedule selected
    var newEvents = [];
    var rotation_length = $('#rotation_type_select option:selected').val();
    var rotation_start_date = new Date(startDate.toISOString());
    var rotation_end_date = new Date(startDate.toISOString());

    //End date is to midnight
    endDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes() + 1);
    rotation_end_date.setDate(rotation_end_date.getDate() + parseInt(rotation_length));

    var member_index = 0;
    while (rotation_end_date <= endDate)
    {
   //     alert('start date: ' + rotation_start_date.toISOString() + ' end date: ' + rotation_end_date.toISOString());
        var event = new Object();
        event = {
            title: memberList[member_index].name,
            start: new Date (rotation_start_date.toISOString()),
            end: new Date (rotation_end_date.toISOString()),
            objectID: memberList[member_index].id,
            color: memberList[member_index].color,
            allDay: true,
            textColor: 'white'
        };
        newEvents.push(event);
        eventsAdded.push(event);

        rotation_start_date.setDate(rotation_start_date.getDate() + parseInt(rotation_length));
        rotation_end_date.setDate(rotation_end_date.getDate() + parseInt(rotation_length));

        if ((memberList.length - 1) == member_index) {
            member_index = 0;
        }
        else {
            member_index++;
        }
    }           
    //Render events on calendar
     $('#edit_calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEvents);
    }); //end create schedule button click
```

The function to convert the dates is the same as below but I renamed the function:

```
function convertTextToDate(dateValue)
{   
    var dateArray = dateValue.split(/\D/);
    var pm = /pm$/i.test(dateValue);
    var hour = (+dateArray[3] || 0) % 12 + (pm ? 12 : 0);
    var date = new Date(Date.UTC(dateArray[2], dateArray[0] - 1, dateArray[1], hour, +dateArray[4] || 0, +dateArray[5] || 0));
    return date;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't your datepicker provide the time as a `Date` object?

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, manually parse them using your own function (a few lines) or a well maintained library.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.prototype.toISOString()` is based on a 0 offset UTC timezone. So it is trying to normalize your current timezone back to 0 UTC, because when you do `new Date()` you create a new date based on your current time zone, that is why the method is trying to revert your date back to UTC time zone. You are probably right now in a time zone which is 4h behind UTC.

http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/toisostring

In order to fix this, just append your string with " UTC" and it will no longer do the timezone shifting:

```
10/23/2015 12:00 AM UTC
```

It will generate:

```
"2015-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it!

Comment: That's a very poor suggestion. There's no standard that requires any browser or ECMAScript implementation to correctly parse a string in that format, so you should not expect that it will be. The reference documentation seems to be poor, you should reference the language specification (ECMAScript 2015) and MDN for examples.

Comment: I actually based my answer off the specification and that link is from MDN (devdocs.io is just a documentation organizer and all the JS docs from from MDN).

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43

15.9.5.43 Date.prototype.toISOString ( )

This function returns a String value represent the instance in time represented by this Date object. The format of the String is the Date Time string format defined in 15.9.1.15. All fields are present in the String. The time zone is always UTC, denoted by the suffix Z. If the time value of this object is not a finite Number a RangeError exception is thrown.

Comment: The behaviour you note in regard to *toISOString* is correct, however your suggestion to parse a non–standard string using the Date constructor is a very bad idea as parsing of strings is almost entirely implementation dependent (and certainly is for the string in the OP, with or without a timezone). MDN is not an authority, it's a public wiki that is better than other (mostly poor) resources.

Comment: Gotcha. I agree with the risk, however it is a matter of testing, if this ends up working for the targeted browsers/platforms, then it might still be a solution. Otherwise, I guess then a more reliable approach would be to adopt http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** use the Date constructor to parse strings, particularly non-standard strings. Ever. Manually parse the string.

Since you have a fixed format, it's pretty straight forward to create a date based on UTC with the format in the OP

```js
// Parse date format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AP as UTC
function parseMDYA(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var pm = /pm$/i.test(s);
  var h = (+b[3]||0)%12 + (pm? 12 : 0);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[2], b[0]-1, b[1], h, +b[4]||0, +b[5]||0));
}

var s = '10/23/2015 12:00 AM';
var d = parseMDYA(s);
document.write('Input string: ' + s +
               '<br>UTC time: ' + d.toISOString() +
               '<br>Local time: ' + d
               );
```

Time parts that aren't supplied are treated as 0.

Comment: When I run the code snippet, the results are the same incorrect value that I get initially: Thu Oct 22 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time).  The time should be 00:00:00.

Comment: The above assumes that the input string is UTC. You are seeing GMT-0400 because you are using the date's own *toString* method, which is implementation dependent but typically returns a string based on the host system's settings for timezone. If you want UTC, then use *toISOString*, which creates an ISO 8601 string with UTC timezone.

Comment: Why does the date still have the timezone shift when you are creating it using .UTC?

Comment: I need the date created to be the date and time of the string because I have to display it on a calendar with that time.

Comment: @GloriaSantin—the time value in Date objects is UTC. They have a time zone offset that is used by default to **display** times. If you use UTC methods to create the date, and UTC methods to display values, the time zone is ignored. *toISOString* uses UTC, always. Hopefully the answer above demonstrates that. ;-)

Comment: This is not what I am seeing in my code.  When I create a Date object using UTC methods and I step thru the code, the date is set with a time zone.  I can display it without the timezone using toISOString() but I need to add to the date objects in a while loop.  When the date has the timezone the addition is incorrect.  So, the parseMDYA function is not working.

Comment: @GloriaSantin—the timezone is a property of a Date instance and represents minutes to subtract from UTC (the opposite of ISO 8601 time zones). The internal [*time value*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range) is UTC. By default, the *toString* method uses the time zone for it's return value. If you want to see the actual internal value, use *getTime*. To see it as a UTC ISO string, use [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring), which is always UTC.